# Pushing my updates, it directly going to main instead of my branch

Tags: github

VSCode Console:

```
PS
\team1\
PS
\team1> git branch
* Mybranch
  main
PS
\team1> git branch -v
* Mybranch 11fbffa Popup Login
  main   03fc57d [behind 6] Merge branch 'main' of https://github.com/myropositorymaster/team1 into main
\team1> git remote show origin
... HEAD branch: main
```

I used console command and also VSCode tools to push; still it's updating and merging into the main directly instead of Mybranch!
can you see something wrong on my branch here?
Thanks for your time

Update: I changed HEAD to Mybranch, still push updating and merging to remote main, but my branch in remote keeps the old one
after fetch --all , stage all or pull, then commit and then

```
git push origin Mybranch
To https://github.com/myropositorymaster/team1
 ! [rejected]        Mybranch -> Mybranch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/myropositorymaster/team1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to my own question as a very professional teacher in North Seattle college (Bob) helped me one-by-one, and solved, that was not easy task.
After some reverse with:
(problem started)

```
git reset --hard origin main
```

and

```
git rm -r --cached .\src\com
```

in some points I was lost synchronizing with main/master and my repo commits were some behind, so with:
(the solution)

```
git merge --abort
```

and then:

```
git checkout -b newBranch
```

the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to your branch in order to push there. First of all use:

```
git fetch --all
```

To retrieve all the new branches that are created so locally you are up to date with origin.

Then in order to move to your branch you do:

```
git checkout Mybranch
```

After this step you will be in your branch (you can try `git status` to verify it)

then you can `add`/`commit`/`push` into your branch

so you can do something like:

```
git add .
git commit -m "just a test commit"
git push origin Mybranch
```

Comment: After these steps and with nothing in version control, I'm getting this error: git push origin Mybranch
To https://github.com/myropositorymaster/team1
 ! [rejected]        Mybranch -> Mybranch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/myropositorymaster/team1'

Comment: Then there is one more command to run :

`git rebase Mybranch`

and then try to add/commit/push